# Multiple Configuration Files with Log4Net

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I would like to have a company wide log4net configuration file but allow individuals to add additional appenders to their on application.  How can I setup Log4Net to incorporate all appenders (from the system wide and the application specific).

I have considered reading in both xml documents and dynamically writing out a combined one but this seems error-prone.

Ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to build a class that merges all the log4net sections in an in-memory XmlDocument and pass this to log4net.

The implementation of this class and its usage can be found on:

http://www.kopf.com.br/kaplof/using-multiple-configuration-files-with-log4net